# Jtable, adicionar multi-linhas[cell span] +Formatar tabela

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Preciso de fazer algo deste género:

[image: jtable]

Neste momento tenho uma tabela como a da imagem 1, mas queria criar uma tabela como a da imagem 2.
Como posso criar algo desse género? Alguma ideia?

O exemplo mais parecido que vi foi:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiLineCellExample.htm

**[EDIT]**

Para criar as multi-linhas usei a esta class "AttributiveCellTableModel" que se encontra no site:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm

Com esse código, consegui implementar o multi-linhas, usando um ciclo que percorre um `Map<String,Map<String,Obejct>>`, a primeira chave corresponde a primeira coluna e o segundo map corresponde as restantes.
O "AttributiveCellTableModel" e um DefaultTableModel.

Codigo:

```
 AttributiveCellTableModel ml=new AttributiveCellTableModel(cont,4);
    final MultiSpanCellTable table = new MultiSpanCellTable( ml );
   
    table.setShowGrid(false);
    table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(2,2));
    table.setBackground(Color.white);
    
    table.setSize(400, 400);
    table.setLocation(10, 10);
    this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    this.add(table);
    final CellSpan cellAtt =(CellSpan)ml.getCellAttribute();
    
     int LineATUAL=0;
     int LineTOTAL=0;      
     for (Map.Entry<String,Map<String,LinhasOnline>>  entry : mapTudo.entrySet()) {
         int INTERVALO=0;
         for (Map.Entry<String, LinhasOnline> produtos : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
             
                INTERVALO++;
                ml.setValueAt(produtos.getValue().getLinha(), LineATUAL, 0);
                ml.setValueAt(produtos.getValue().getProduto(), LineATUAL, 1);
                ml.setValueAt(produtos.getValue().getcont(), LineATUAL, 2);
                ml.setValueAt(produtos.getValue().getmax(), LineATUAL, 3);
                
                System.out.println("linha:" +LineATUAL);
                LineATUAL++;
         }
         mapSpanCell.put(entry.getKey(), INTERVALO);
    }
     for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapSpanCell.entrySet()) {
         System.out.println("nome linha entry" +entry.getKey());
     }
     for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapSpanCell.entrySet()) {
         //usadp para mandar parar todos os ciclos em baixo
         breakcycle:
         for (int i = 0; i < ml.getRowCount(); i++) {
             
             if(ml.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(entry.getKey())){
                 if(entry.getValue()>1){
                     System.out.println("vorrrraasd: "+entry.getValue());
                     int[] intervalo = new int[entry.getValue()];
                     for(int xx=0, y=i; y<i+entry.getValue();y++, xx++){
                         intervalo[xx]=y;
                         System.out.println("valor do Y" +y);
                     }
                     int[] columnss = {0};
//                         int[] rowss = intervalo;
                     cellAtt.combine(intervalo, columnss);
                     
                     break breakcycle;
                     
                 }
                 else {
                     System.out.println(" ola");
                 } 
             }
         }
    }
```

Que me retorna esta tabela:

[image: tabela]

Agora queria adicionar duas coisas:

- Adicionar o nome das colunas
- E remover as linhas verticais

Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Para esconder as linhas verticais da sua tabela basta usar o método `setShowVerticalLines()` do seu objeto JTable passando o argumento `false`.

```
tabela.setShowVerticalLines(false);
```

Para mostrar o cabeçalho você deve colocar o JTable dentro de um JScrollPane.

```
scroll = new JScrollPane(tabela);
contentPane.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Para os exemplos acima considere que eu criei os atributos à nível de classe, ou seja, assim:

```
private JScrollPane scroll;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable tabela;
```

Comment: Ja tinha tentado esses códigos mas voltei a tentar, e mesmo assim não consegui. Penso que quanto as linhas verticais o problema é que a class AttributiveCellTableModel implementa o metodo paint para desenhar as celulas penso que deve ser isso...

Comment: Quanto ao nome das colunas todos os exemplos que vi tem código do género do teu mas mesmo assim também ainda não consegui resolver

Comment: Sendo assim terei que analisar o código que pôs no link, pois existem algumas modificações por trás das cenas que devem estar causando esses efeitos indesejáveis. Se o seu código não for muito grande poderia postá-lo completo no corpo da sua pergunta, se for grande pode deixar o link do jeito que está mesmo.

Comment: Ainda é um pouco grande sim, se der para tentares dar uma olhada era muito bom, mas se for preciso eu coloco, porque estou a ter muitos problemas, queria muito por no meu programa uma tabela destas mas não está nada fácil.